# React native render header method

Tags: react-native

How can i call renderHeader of a ListView?
I tried the following code but nothing happens

```
this.refs.listview.props.renderHeader()
```

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 3):

You need to pass in a renderHeader method which returns a JSX element, like the code below demonstrates:

```
<ListView renderHeader={this.renderHeader} dataSource={this.state.dataSource} renderRow={this.renderRow} />
```

I've also set up a very basic project demonstrating how do to this [here](https://rnplay.org/apps/fuYP5Q). The code is below as well. Hope this answers your question!

https://rnplay.org/apps/fuYP5Q

```
'use strict';

var React = require('react-native');
var {
  AppRegistry,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  ListView
} = React;

var SampleApp = React.createClass({

  getInitialState: function() {
    var ds = new ListView.DataSource({rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1 !== r2});
    return { 
      dataSource: ds.cloneWithRows([]),
      data: ['row1', 'row2', 'row3', 'row4', 'row5', 'row6']
    }

  },

  componentDidMount: function() {
    var ds = new ListView.DataSource({rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1 !== r2})
    this.setState({
        dataSource: ds.cloneWithRows(this.state.data)
    })
  },

  renderHeader: function() {
    return <View style={{backgroundColor:'red', height:60}}><Text style={{color: 'white', fontSize:20, textAlign:'center'}}>Header</Text></View>
  },

  renderRow:function(data) {
    return <View style={{height:50, borderWidth:1, marginBottom:5}}><Text  style={{textAlign:'center'}} >{data}</Text></View>
  },

  render: function() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <ListView renderHeader={this.renderHeader} dataSource={this.state.dataSource} renderRow={this.renderRow} />
      </View>
    );
  }
});

var styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    marginTop:100
  }
});

AppRegistry.registerComponent('SampleApp', () => SampleApp);
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for trying to help me.
My issue was that after adding new items to the list I wanted to change the header style and animation. so I thought about re-rendering the header, but eventually I bound that style and animation object to the this.state, so.. problem solved.